# How to create a new object in a collection that have a populate field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm currently on a school project. I have to create a web site and I wanted to do a MEAN app. All was fine until I wanted to design good models for mongoose. I will have Users (name, psswd, etc ) in one collection and I will have their "detailed information" in another collection.

I know how to query, find and assemble the data. It's all in the mongoose documentation but...

I don't know how to create (when answering a POST request) the new user with it's dedicated "detailed information".

What is the populate method for :

```
~User.cardid.create()~ ?
~
var cardIDSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userID: String,
  name: String,
  surname: String,
  date_Of_Birth: Date,
  address: String,

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: String,
  psswd: String,
  cardID: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'CardID'}
});~
```

Comment: You should store everything together unless you have some kind of one to many relation.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of that, I just wanted to play

Comment: When you instantiate your model are you setting its name/ref to "CarID"  for exmaple. mongoose.model("CardID", CardIDSchema) ??

Comment: Yeah i'm doing this plus the same for the User

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're coming from the **SQL** world, the `populate` method works like the `join` statement where it uses the reference column in one table to fetch the corresponding items for external tables. In your schema above, if you were to fetch a use and wish to retrieve the accompanying `detailed information`, you use the `populate` method like so `User.findOne().populate('cardId');`

I've modified the schema below to make it easier.

To create a new user with corresponding detailed information with this schema:

```
var cardIDSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  surname: String,
  date_Of_Birth: Date,
  address: String,
})

var Card = mongoose.model('Card', cardIDSchema);

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: String,
  psswd: String,
  cardID: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'CardID'}
});

const User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
```

you have to create the card information first to get the `ObjectId` then the user follows.

```
//...
// Create the card first.
var card = new Card({
  name: 'Some',
  surname: 'Person',
  date_Of_Birth: Date.now(),
  address: 'Somewhere in the world'
}); // this will create a new card._id automatically

// Create the user and pass the card._id as the reference.
var user = new User({
  email: 'test@example.org',
  psswd: 'somesecret',
  cardID: card._id
});

/**
 * Depending on if you're using an async/await function...
 */
// For async...
// Save the card information first.
await card.save();

// Then save the user information.
await user.save();


// For callbacks...
card.save(function (err) {
    if (err) ; // Do something with error.

    user.save(function (err) {
        if (err) ; // Do something with the error.
});

//...
```

To retrieve the model is even easier, which is why the `populate` method was created.

```
//...

// Say the id of the user you created was '5cd47029324acd59fc666df6'
// Using the async/await function...
var user = await User.findById('5cd47029324acd59fc666df6').populate('cardID');

// Using callback...
User.findById('5cd47029324acd59fc666df6')
    .populate('cardID')
    .exec(function (err, user) {
        if (err) ; // Do something with error.

        // Continue with user here...
    });

// The user variable will then be...
/**
 * {
 *    _id: '5cd47029324acd59fc666df6',
 *    email: 'test@example.org',
 *    psswd: 'somesecret',
 *    cardID: {
 *        _id: '5cd47652324acd59fc666df7',
 *        name: 'Some',
 *        surname: 'Person',
 *        date_Of_Birth: Date.now(),
 *        address: 'Somewhere in the world'
 *    }
 * }
 */

//...
```

**P.S.**: To ensure consistency, use the `fawn` npm module which imitates a sort of transactional state to ensure that all data is saved before proceeding and if one of the models isn't save, the initially saved model will be deleted from the database.